# Using Java3D in eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, java-3d

I'm going to develop an Eclipse plugin for my work and I'm wondering if it is possible to create a view with a 3D canvas made through a 3D library like Java3D or JMonkeyEngine.

If it's possible can you please point me to a tutorial from which I can start (I'm not asking for a complete solution, just some ideas on how to procede)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try [gef3d](http://eclipse.org/gef3d/)

Comment: Is it based on Java3D? Or it uses a direct OpenGL mapping?

Comment: in this article (http://jaxenter.com/gef-goes-3d-10076.html) is stated that they use OpenGL for rendering